# cron job not running in night in iisnode

Tags: node.js, cron, iisnode

We have a MEAN stack application. It is deployed on iisnode. We have written a cron job using npm cron module.cron is not running until we hit the URL. We think iisnode become idle. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Please provide detailed description of problem

Comment: when we set time in cron in day time and hit the url of application which is deployed in iisnode cron is always triggering and giving expected output.but  in night time when there is no hit to url means iisnode is not receiving any request then cron is not triggering.Please give inputs on this.

Answer (score 3):

IIS will close the process if the pool becomes idle. You should config it like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41700802/3645375):

1. Open IIS(intemgr).
2. Go to Application Pools.
3. Right click on the pool which runs your nodeJS app.
4. Choose Advanced Settings.
5. Set "Idle Time-Out" under the Process Model section to "0".