# Nuxt SSR on plesk have to restart every ≈5minutes

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, plesk, standby

I have a server.js file who start my nuxt SSR website. First load of the website is a bit slow but it's ok. The time to start and finish the 'npm run start' command take around 8secs then the app is ready for every other users.
Around 5 minutes laters, if nobody come on the website, it's seems to go in standby...
New users will have to wait around 8 seconds, the time the 'npm run start' need to be ready again.

So my question, how can i keep my nuxt.js website awake so it nobody have to wait for the restart?
The server.js file is below.

I use plesk (windows).

```js
const express = require("express");
const {
  loadNuxt
} = require("nuxt");
const config = require("./nuxt.config.js");

const app = express();

config.dev = false;
async function start() {
  const nuxt = await loadNuxt("start");
  app.use(nuxt.render);
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
start();
```

Comment: Is plesk a service or is it installed on a VPS?

Comment: @kissu it's installed on my server

Answer (score 0):

Well, i solved my problem...
It was not a nuxt problem but a plesk/ IIS problem ( idle timeout iisnode exactly).

If you have similar issue, have a look at this page : [iisnode making the node process always working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693191/iisnode-making-the-node-process-always-working)